# xcodebuild command but it exited with error code 74

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am trying to run my react-native project. With the android app I have no problem, but when I run

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

I get the title error and at the end of the ran iOS, I get this to:

> target 'FBSDKLoginKit' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at '/Users/myuser/Documents/Test/my-app/ios/build/Test/SourcePackages/checkouts/facebook-ios-sdk/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/include/FBSDKLoginKit.h', but directories exist next to it: /Users/myuser/Documents/Test/my-app/ios/build/Test/SourcePackages/checkouts/facebook-ios-sdk/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/include/include; consider removing them

As configurations, I have:

- node 14.17.0
- Xcode 13.4.1
- "react": "16.9.0",
- "react-native": "0.61.3",

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though that somehow, my xcodeproj was influencing my build, so I tried to remove the fbsdk, as I didn't need anymore, and this steps were necessary:

1- Removing in package.json

> "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",

2- Removing directly in the file **iOS/Myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj** this part of the code:

```
/* Begin XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */
        D3321AC724E5D77B000A3C6F /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "facebook-ios-sdk" */ = {
            isa = XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference;
            repositoryURL = "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk";
            requirement = {
                kind = upToNextMajorVersion;
                minimumVersion = 7.1.1;
            };
        };
 /* End XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference section */

 /* Begin XCSwiftPackageProductDependency section */
        D3321AC824E5D77B000A3C6F /* FacebookCore */ = {
            isa = XCSwiftPackageProductDependency;
            package = D3321AC724E5D77B000A3C6F /* XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference "facebook-ios-sdk" */;
            productName = FacebookCore;
        };
 /* End XCSwiftPackageProductDependency section */
```

3- On terminal, ran:

```
yarn
```

4- Than:

```
cd ios && pod install
```

5- Finally:

```
cd .. && npx react-native run-ios
```

(it didn't fix entirely, but the error changed)